# How to get the date for the start of the week (Monday) by passing in the current day?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get the date for the start of the week (start of the week is the Monday) given the current date. So for e.g. if today is 27-Mar-18, then the formula should return 26-Mar-18. If today is 31-Mar-18, then the formula should still give me 26-Mar-18. If the current date was 24-Mar-18, the formula should return 19-Mar-18.

How would I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `=A1-WEEKDAY(A1,3)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this formula for a date in A2,

```
=A2-WEEKDAY(A2, 2)+1
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked great. Can you help walk me through this formula.

Comment: You can find official documentation for the [WEEKDAY function here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a). Use Formulas, Formula Auditing, Evaluate formula to step through the calculations.